# How to collect site view statistics such as daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly views by using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently building an admin interface for a website and I am using PHP and MySQL. How can I collect the view count and classify it by day, week, month and year?

Comment: Where is your best attempt in order to get your expected result?

Comment: @B001ᛦ I simply just stored a record of all visits with a UNIX timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need accurate statistics, you can create a table for all visits like this :

```
+----+----------------------------+------------------+
| id |            Info            | date             |
+----+----------------------------+------------------+
| 1  | {"use_proxy":true,ecc...}  | 28/03/2020 10:00 |
+----+----------------------------+------------------+
| 2  | {"use_proxy":false,ecc...} | 20/04/2020 10:00 |
+----+----------------------------+------------------+
| 3  | {"use_proxy":false,ecc...} | 05/02/2020 10:22 |
+----+----------------------------+------------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `views` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Info` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    `date` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

can you use this query to select number of view by specific date :

```
SELECT SUM(id) AS views FROM views WHERE DAY(date) = 05 && MONTH(date) = 02 && YEAR(date) = 2020
```